# Is there a way to use Python to open specific webpages after typing in input?

Tags: python, python-webbrowser

I'm trying to find a way to write a script that accepts input from the user, After which, it will open webpages. The code looks like this so far:

```
jurisdiction = input("Enter jurisdiction:")
if jurisdiction = 'UK':
    import webbrowser
    webbrowser.open('https://www.legislation.gov.uk/new')
    webbrowser.open('https://eur-lex.europa.eu/oj/direct-access.html')
elif jurisdiction = Australia:
    import webbrowswer
    webbrowser.open('https://www.legislation.gov.au/WhatsNew')
else:
    print("Re-enter jurisdiction")
```

This leads to a syntax error at line 3:

```
File "UK.py", line 3
if jurisdiction = UK
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax**
```

I would like to know if there is anything in the code that I have missed or should not have had there? Also, is there an alternative way to do what I am trying to achieve here?

Comment: Use `==` instead of `=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend reading up on Python String Comparison. Easy fix, but you would benefit from a basic understanding of how string comparison does and does not work in Python.

Both UK and Australia need to be Strings as well...

And don't import webbroswer package in the body of your code. You only need to do it once.

```
import webbrowser

jurisdiction = input("Enter jurisdiction:")
if jurisdiction == 'UK':
    webbrowser.open('https://www.legislation.gov.uk/new')
    webbrowser.open('https://eur-lex.europa.eu/oj/direct-access.html')
elif jurisdiction == 'Australia':
    webbrowser.open('https://www.legislation.gov.au/WhatsNew')
else:
    print("Re-enter jurisdiction")
```

Answer (score 0):

A cleaner approach:

```
import webbrowser

mapping = {'UK': ['https://www.legislation.gov.uk/new', 'https://eur-lex.europa.eu/oj/direct-access.html'],
           'Australia': ['https://www.legislation.gov.au/WhatsNew']}

jurisdiction = input("Enter jurisdiction:")
urls = mapping.get(jurisdiction)
if urls is not None:
    for url in urls:
        webbrowser.open(url)
else:
    print("Re-enter jurisdiction")
```